# Can I access network-manager.nmcli from another snap?

Tags: network-manager, application-development, ubuntu-core, interface, nmcli

I need to be able to access network-manager.nmcli command from my snap. I have not found a way to accomplish this with the current core or network-manager interfaces. Is the only solution that a slot will have to be created in the network-manager snap to give access to the 'nmcli' command? Or am I missing something?